# Symfony 2: how to fire code before EVERY controller-action?

Tags: php, symfony, event-handling, hook

I'd like to check, if the user is logged in - before *the* action gets called.

Something like a `preDispatch()` for `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` would be great.

I'd like to **avoid** this:

```
class MyBaseController extends Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        // ...
        // check: logged in?
        // ...
    }
}

class MyFooController extends MyBaseController() {
    // ...
}
```

I just found topics from 2011/2012. I'm new to Symfony, using version 2.5 and would like to know the best-practice right from the beginning. Any advices?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:

interesting: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1/ You can [setup before (and also after) filters with the `kernel.controller` Event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html).
Here's a good example from [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html).

- [Before Filters with the kernel.controller Event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#token-validation-example)

2/ You can also create an event Listener which [listens to the `kernel.request` even](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-request-event)t and check if the user is authenticated before targeting any controller.

It's the first event dispatched by the HttpKernel and it's mainly used to add information to the Request or return an early Response when needed (for example to deny access for non-authenticated users or users that don't have permission to access any given resource).

You can also create a listener on [the `kernel.controller` event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-controller-event) (as explained in the example from the documentation I listed before). This event is dispatched after the controller callable has been determined by the HttpKernel. It's mainly used to initialise things before the controller is executed, it's also used to change the controller to execute

You've to read [the HttpKernel component documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html) to get the big picture of how does Symfony behave internally.

3/ You can also use the [@Security annotation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html) which restricts access on controllers,

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

class MyFooController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
     */
    public function anyAction()
    {
        // ...
```

Comment: I have created a bundle based of the Symfony Cookbook which allows for a "before filter".

https://github.com/expertcoder/before-after-bundle

Hopefully you find it useful, I invite any constructive criticism of the bundle. Thanks